# bash append content of two files matching an index

Tags: bash, awk

I have two files, file1

```
    a
    b
    c
    d
    e
    f
    g
    h
    i
    j
```

and file2

```
    b
    c zzz uuu
    d qqq lll
    a xxx ggg
    f
    b
    g
    e rrr ppp
```

I'd like to append the content of file2 to file1 if there's a match of the number, however, I'd also like to print the non-matching lines of file1 without altering the order.
The desired effect is therefore

```
    a xxx ggg
    b
    c zzz uuu
    d qqq lll
    e rrr ppp
    f
    g
    h
    i
    j
```

The matching column can be repeated also, it's not an issue, so it could also be

```
    a a xxx ggg
    b b
    c c zzz uuu
    d d qqq lll
    e e rrr ppp
    f f
    g g
    h h
    i i
    j j
```

I tried

```
    awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next} ($1 in a) {print a[$1],$0}' a b
```

but the result is

```
    b b
    c c zzz uuu
    d d qqq lll
    a a xxx ggg
    f f
    b b
    g g
    e e rrr ppp
```

so the order is lost and there are missing lines from file1, any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

`awk 'FNR==NR{val=$1;$1="";sub(/^ +/,"");a[val]=$0;next}  {print $0,a[$1]}'   Input_file2  Input_file1`

Explanation:

Checking condition here `FNR==NR` which means when value if FNR is equal NR then do following. This condition will be true when 1st Inpit_file2 is being read.

Now creating a variable named `val` whose value is first field then nullifying 1st field and substituting initial space with NULL.

Now creating an array named a whose index is variable val and value is current line.

Using `next` will skip all further statements from here.

Now printing 1st field and then printing a[$1] value in case that value is NOT present it will leave it blank.

Comment: I see your answer is exactly same as the OP's desired output while my result contains extra spaces :)

Comment: Yes,  have taken care of it buddy. Cheers and thank you.

Comment: Great explanation ++

Comment: @anunhava, Thank you sir for encouragement sir.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a=$1;$1="";b[a]=$0;next} {print $1, b[$1]}' file2 file1
```

Result:

```
a  xxx ggg
b
c  zzz uuu
d  qqq lll
e  rrr ppp
f
g
h
i
j
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the real file1 is sorted like your example is:

```
$ join -j1 -o 0,2.2,2.3 -a1 file1.txt <(sort -u file2.txt)    
a xxx ggg
b  
c zzz uuu
d qqq lll
e rrr ppp
f  
g  
h  
i  
j
```

Answer (score 0):

The other way around:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{b[$1]=$0;next} {print $0,b[$1]}' b a
```